# Is there a way to see deleted questions?

Tags: discussion

I like to learn from my past mistakes and see what's wrong. Looks like a lot of my previous questions are deleted.

I understand I am a bad questioner. I should learn more. Would anyone that can see my deleted questions show me those questions so I can study it before I am asking another. Perhaps I should just ask those questions somewhere else.

Yes there have been feedback. I can't see those feedback anymore :( Can I see it for one last time, perhaps at my mail or something?

The mod in philophy stack exchange copy and paste my deleted questions for me. If it doesn't trouble a mod, I'll really appreciate if I can see that. I'll then just move on to other places.

Answer (score 1):

No, only moderators can see deleted question on a user profile. There is no easy way for you to see all of your deleted posts.

You can see your own deleted answers, and 10k user can see all deleted answers as well. 10k user can also see deleted questions, but only if they still have the direct link to the question, they have no easy way of finding deleted questions, except for very recently deleted ones.

And for the record, you have 18 out of 29 questions deleted here on Skeptics. There has been feedback on those questions via the close reason and also comments posted by users and moderators. That should be completely sufficient for you to see what kind of questions you should and shouldn't ask here.

Comment: Does this mean that when I have diligently posted a comment explaining the reason for a deletion, the original author can't see it? That's rather disappointing.

Comment: Has it always been this way? I thought you were allowed to see all deleted answers/questions you owned, and 10K rep could see all deleted stuff.

Comment: @Oddthinking It works fine for comments on answers, but for questions they might still get them in the inbox, but won't be able to see the deleted question.

Comment: The comment *will* appear in the inbox, but unless the user has >= 10K he won't be able to read the whole thing or read it in context, @Oddthinking. Good reason to comment when *closing* - get the rationale and ensuing discussion out of the way *before* deletion.

Comment: I understand I am a bad questioner. I should learn more. Would anyone that can see my deleted questions show me those questions so I can study it before I am asking another. Perhaps I should just ask those questions somewhere else.

Comment: Yes there have been feedback. I can't see those feedback anymore :( Can I see it for one last time, perhaps at my mail or something?

Comment: The mod in philophy stack exchange copy and paste my deleted questions for me. If it doesn't trouble a mod, I'll really appreciate if I can see that.