# If it's not too much trouble, would any mod allow me to see my deleted questions for the last time?

Tags: support, status-declined

I just want to ask them somewhere else and learn from my mistake.

Thanks.

Philosophy stack exchange mod do that for me easily. I wonder if some mod would do this for me.

I'll really appreciate that.

[Is there a way to see deleted questions?](https://skeptics.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1800/is-there-a-way-to-see-deleted-questions) says that I got 18 questions deleted. If I can see those 18 it'll be great.

Answer (score 5):

Those posts are deleted for a reason, and I see no reason to make them accessible again. You have received a lot of feedback on your posts, that should be sufficient for you to learn to post good content here. If all that wasn't enough, I don't see how giving you those old deleted questions would do any good.

And if you want to ask them somewhere else instead of learning from your mistakes, I'd rather spare those other sites the trouble of having to close and delete them again. This is not a matter of just being off-topic on Skeptics, most of your deleted questions are just plain not constructive, borderline or blatant trolling or just a rant about your favorite subject. Those are not welcome on any SE site.

Comment: I received a lot of feedback, they're gone before I saw them :( You can email me so no one else have to see those.

Comment: While I agree with Fabian's answer, @JimThio does have a point. I've had questions deleted before I could read comments on my post (in my case, I had answered a question, received comments, then the question was deleted before I could read the comments on my answer).  That is certainly a frustrating situation. I don't have a clever suggestoin for a solution, though.

Comment: Yea just show me the title then. Otherwise people would think some dark conspiracy tries to smother good questions :D